# Deserialize XML to object in C# using Windows Device Project

Tags: c#, deserialization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.XmlConfiguration;
using OATAssetTracking.Solution.Presenter;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]

    static void Main()
    {

        string path = "SearchDefinition.xml";
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add(null, @"D:\searchDefinition.xsd");

        Exception firstException = null;

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            Schemas = schemas,
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            ValidationFlags =
                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
        };
        settings.ValidationEventHandler +=
            delegate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
            {
                if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (firstException == null)
                    {
                        firstException = args.Exception;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
                }
            };

        Search result=null;

        using (var input = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(input, settings))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Search));
                result = (Search)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        if (firstException != null)
        {
            throw firstException;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Deserialization Done!!!!");


         }
}
```

}

In this one,

Here Search is class name which is generated from XSD

result = (Search)ser.Deserialize(reader);

This above statement works fine in Windows forms Application, but fails to work with Windows Device Project " No errors but just hangs there not executing".

Comment: Erhm... just curious, what is a "WIndows Device" project? I have VS2015 pro and can't find that project type... maybe you mean UWP?

Comment: The project is Smart Device Project which comes under .NET Framework 3.5 in VS2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, The problem in the above code was

result = (Search)ser.Deserialize(reader);

XML reader which has been created cannot be used while directly de-serializing it to an object. This kind of above code is supported only in the "Windows Forms Application" in VS2008 and its not getting supported in any kind of "Smart Device Projects".

So, Reader settings can be included and XML errors can be handled by any handlers like ValidationEventHandler.

So, Below code validates the XML against XSD and also de-serializes to the object initialized.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;
using OATAssetTracking.Solution.Presenter;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string path2 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\" + "SearchDefinition.xsd";
        string path1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\" + "SearchDefinition.xml";

        XmlSchema schema;
        using (var schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(path2))
        {
            schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, ValidationEventHandler);
        }

        var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add(schema);

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas = schemas;
        settings.ValidationFlags =
            XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
            XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;

        using (var validationReader = XmlReader.Create(path1, settings))
        {
            while (validationReader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("XML verified Successfully....");

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Search));

        Search result = ser.Deserialize(new FileStream(path1, FileMode.Open)) as Search;

        MessageBox.Show("Deserilization Done Successfully!!!!");


    }

    private static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
        {
            throw args.Exception;
        }

     }
}
}
```